# Error on passing values in SqlCommand query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

What am I doing wrong here? I just want a dynamic method which can count any column depending on the value. But getting a runtime error.

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '='."

[image: Error]

```
public class DataAccessLayerPayroll
{
     public static string CountTblColumByValue(string columName,string value)
    {
        String cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BD_CompanyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            string sqlQuery ="Select Count("+columName+") from tblAttendance1 where"+columName+"='"+value+"'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);

            con.Open();
            object count = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            return count.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is clear and that query is wide open to SQL injection attacks and conversion errors. Imagine what would happen if you passed an invalid character as a collumn name or a space. Or if a malicious user wrote `'; drop table users;--` in a textbox.

Comment: Error: missing space after `where`. BIG ERROR: These type of queries prone to SQL Injections

Comment: Use an ORM like EF and create the query using LINQ, eg `var count=myContext.Attendance.Where(att=>att.Whatever=someValue).Count();` or `Where(...).Select(att=>att.SomeColumn).Distinct().Count()` etc

Comment: It's not only malicious input that can break such queries. What would happen when you pass a date or decimal? The value will be converted to a string using the user's locale which can be different from the server's and result in strings that will be parsed in the wrong way by the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you're missing some space between `where "+columName+"= '"+value+"'"`

But the bigger issue is that your command is **exposed to SQL injection**. To prevent this use parameterized queries.

Change it as the following way

```
public static string CountTblColumByValue(string columnName, string value)
{
    String cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BD_CompanyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        string sqlQuery ="Select Count(@myColumName) from tblAttendance1 where @myColumName = @myValue ";

        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con))
        {
           con.Open();
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myColumName", columnName);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myValue", value);

           object count = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

           return count.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you **cannot** use parameters for table or column **names** - only for the values. This code does **NOT** work ....

Comment: Thanx for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

```
string sqlQuery ="Select Count("+columName+") from tblAttendance1 whereYOU ARE MISSING A SPACE HERE"+columName+"='"+value+"'";
```

So your code must be like following:

```
string sqlQuery ="Select Count("+columName+") from tblAttendance1 where "+columName+"='"+value+"'";
```

Answer (score -1):

The basic error in your code is missing space between `where` and `=`

Also, You should definitely fix the `SqlInjection` as suggested in other answers. (*You cannot use parameters for column name though*)

After that, you also should see that according to `Count` definition you will only get `count` of `not null` values.

> `Count()` function returns the number of records in a select query (only Not Null) values.

Also see how will you achieve following:

1) count `null` values only

2) count all `not null` values

3) count number/date operations i.e. `<`, `>`, `between`

If you don’t need these scenarios in your code, then you have the answer to the error in your sql.

Comment: Maybe I answered too much. Simplified answer @shezan zahid